# preconfigure filter affecting widget with disabled apply global filters

Tags: einstein-analytics, filters, saql, einstein-analytics-dashboards

I have embedded a wave dashboard on a visualforce page. 
In my dashboard I have charts that "Apply global filters is disabled".
What happen is when I view the dashboard on the visual force page, and clicked the button "Open in Analytics Studio"
the global filter on the dashboard become preconfigured filters that is also said on the release plan "winter 18 release notes" https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_bi_design_global_filter.htm.

The problem is when I view the dashboard on the visual force page, and clicked the button "Open in Analytics Studio"
the global filter on the dashboard becomes preconfigured filters. Those preconfigured filter also affecting steps that has
setup "Apply global filters is disabled."

Is there a possible solution or work around to avoid affecting steps with preconfigured filters?

Answer (score 1):

Can you check and confirm if the button "Open in Analytics Studio" is a link widget?

If yes, uncheck "Apply Filters and Selections" checkbox in widget property.

That should solve the issue for you.

Comment: Hi Kaushik, Thanks for this reply. How to check if the button Open Analytics Stuidio is a link widget, where to check it. Thanks by the way

Comment: Open the dashboard in Analytics in edit mode. Click on the button to see the details.